# Kerberos Enabled Remote Hive Meta Store (hive-1.1.0) access issue Using Spark (1.6.0) SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

My Hive version is 1.1.0 and spark is 1.6.0
No issue with connection . I am able to make connection successful.

After connection while importing data or creating data link using hive connection I can see Database name and tables belongs to it but getting error 
 (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx-nameservice`)while retrieving data from table. Below is my code:

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", prop.getProperty("hive.metastore.uris"))
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", prop.getProperty("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled"))
hiveContext.setConf("hive.security.authorization.enabled", prop.getProperty("hive.security.authorization.enabled"))
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", prop.getProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal"))
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", prop.getProperty("hive.metastore.execute.setugi"))
hiveContext.sql("use abc")   
hiveContext.sql("show tables").show(4) // This is working
hiveContext.sql("select * from abc.tab1 limit 10").show(2)
```

Below is the issue:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx-nameservice
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:728)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2819)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat.listStatus(AvroContainerInputFormat.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)

Comment: The Metastore just stores metadata -- i.e. databases, tables, partitions, columns, and where the data **files** are stored. Then Spark has to connect to **HDFS** to read these files. Did you setup `core-site.xml` in `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` ?

Comment: I am trying to connect Remote Metastore from One cluster to other cluster.